# Page not found (404) - Django urls and views

Tags: python, django, django-views, webserver, django-urls

I'm trying to make a web server with Django for making "parrot bot".

I'm using 
python3.5
Django
apache2.4

The error I'm getting :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://54.95.30.145/
Using the URLconf defined in bot.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^keyboard/
^message
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

This is my project bot/urls.py code.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'',include('inform.urls')),
]
```

This is my app inform/urls.py code.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^keyboard/',views.keyboard),
    url(r'^message',views.message),
]
```

This is my inform/views.py code.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def keyboard(request):
    return JsonResponse({
            'type' : 'text',
    })

def message(request):
    message = ((request.body).decode('utf-8'))
    return_json_str = json.loads(message)
    return_str = return_json_str['contetn']

    return JsonResponse({
            'message': {
                    'text' : return_str
            }
    })
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It error is nothing but you didn't define any `url patterns` for your `root` address (`http://54.95.30.145/`).
To solve this, add a url pattern for home/root address as below in `project bot/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include


def root_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({"message": "This is root"})


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', root_view),
    url(r'', include('inform.urls')),
]
```